# Translate object, stopping, and continuing- Processing

Tags: java, object, for-loop, transform, processing

I'm trying to move an object (rectangle for our purposes), from point A to D.  However, along the way I want to stop the motion at different segments and wait some time.

For example, I want to move from A to B, wait 5 seconds, then move from B to C, wait 2 seconds.  Finally, move from C to D.

I've tried a couple of things.  First I moved my object by giving it a "speed" (xspeed) and increasing its position (xpos) by xspeed.  Then using an if statement I stopped the position when it reaches 100.  I then count 5 seconds and begin motion again.  However, since the motion starts past the x-position 100, the if-statement does not allow me to move forward.  I don't know if I can override this if statement.  Below is the code of what I did:

```
  class Pipe {
  color c;
  float xpos;
  float ypos;
  float xspeed;
  int time;

  Pipe(color c_, float xpos_, float ypos_, float xspeed_) {
    c = c_;
    xpos = xpos_;
    ypos = ypos_;
    xspeed = xspeed_;
  }

  void display() {
    noStroke();
    fill(c);
    rectMode(CENTER);
    rect(xpos,ypos,10,200);
  }


  void pipeMove() {
    xpos = xpos + xspeed;
    if (xpos > 100) {
      xpos = 100;
      if (millis() > time) {
        time = millis()+5000;
        xpos = xpos + xspeed;
      }
    }
  }
}

Pipe myPipe1;
Pipe myPipe2;

void setup() {
  size(1500,500);
  myPipe1 = new Pipe(color(85,85,85),0,height/2,2);
//  myPipe2 = new Pipe(color(85,85,85),-100,height/2,2);
}

void draw() {
  background(255);
  myPipe1.display();
  myPipe1.pipeMove();
//  myPipe2.display();
//  myPipe2.pipeMove();
}
```

The other option I tried was stopping the automatic looping in Processing by using noLoop(), and looping the position within my class.  However, this does not move my object.  See code below of my for-loop.

```
class Pipe {
  color c;
  float xpos;
  float ypos;
  float xspeed;
  int time;

  Pipe(color c_, float xpos_, float ypos_, float xspeed_) {
    c = c_;
    xpos = xpos_;
    ypos = ypos_;
    xspeed = xspeed_;
  }

  void display() {
    noStroke();
    fill(c);
    rectMode(CENTER);
    rect(xpos,ypos,10,200);
  }


  void pipeMove() {
    for (int i = 0; i<100; i = i+1) {
    xpos = xpos + i;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're on the right track with your first approach. You've got the first part working, now you just need to add in the other steps. One way to solve this might be to use **states** in your `Pipe` class.

By that I mean, you just have to keep track of which step the pipe is currently on, and then do the right thing depending on which step you're on. The simplest way to do this might be to add booleans into your `Pipe` class:

```
class Pipe {
  color c;
  float xpos;
  float ypos;
  float xspeed;
  int time;

  boolean movingToA = true;
  boolean waitingAtA = false;
  boolean movingToB = false;
  //...
```

And then in your `pipeMove()` function, just do the right thing depending on which state you're in, and change the state to change the behavior:

```
  void pipeMove() {

    if (movingToA) {

      xpos = xpos + xspeed;

      if (xpos > 100) {
        xpos = 100;
        movingToA = false;
        waitingAtA = true;
        time = millis();
      }
    } else if (waitingAtA) {
      if (millis() > time + 5000) {
        waitingAtA = false;
        movingToB = true;
      }
    } else if (movingToB) {
      xpos = xpos + xspeed;

      if (xpos > 200) {
        xpos = 200;
        movingToB = false;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

There are some pretty obvious improvements to be made here- you could use enum values, or a data structure of potential actions, or parameterize the behavior, for example. But the basics are the same: perform different actions depending on which state you're in, and then change that state to change the behavior.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense.  I'm going to to give it a go.  Thanks!